# The size of an array

Tags: c++

Is it true that the size of an array has to be a constant variable? Like for example,

```
const int size = 5;//would int size = 5 not be allowed?
int array[size];
```

Also if this this is true what happens when you work with dynamic arrays? Would `int size = 5;` be fine then?

Comment: It has to be a compile-time constant. It doesn't have to be a named constant.

Comment: Are you talking about c++ standard or g++ compiler extension?

Comment: Sounds like a [good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is what you need. Learning by trial/error and SO isn't effective.

Comment: I just mean, what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: For static array's yes, it has to be a compile time constant.  Dynamic arrays reallocate memory on the heap as needed.

Comment: Things to research: [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size). Advice: Stay away from C-style arrays in C++.

Comment: "what is the right way of doing it?" - the right way is to *not* do it. If you need a dynamic array use `std::vector`. For a static array use `std::array`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I mean, if im just using a standard array, the variable has to be const.

Comment: @filipanton1 as others have already said. It has to be *a compile time constant*. But, just use `std::array` or `std::vector` already.

Comment: The size of a static array must be const and known at compile time, although some compilers are not so fuzzy and will allow it to be a runtime variable, but that is not portable and bad practice.

Comment: The size of an array must be `constexpr`. Being `const` is just not enough, due to the possibility of having `const` variable, which has value computed at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, yes, arrays have to have a compile time value (explicit content or a constant variable).

Variable Length Arrays are C99, and a GCC extension. You should not use them in C++, even if g++ allows them.